# Последовательное обращение к БД Oracle

Tags: oracle, java

Доброго времени суток!

Уважаемые коллеги, у меня возникла следующая проблема. Пишу простенькое приложение с использованием базы данных Oracle XE, все хорошо, написал уровень персистинга с несколькими методами (добавления, изменения, удаления) данных из БД, но внезапно возникла следующая проблема: при одновременном (последовательном) вызове методов обращения к БД вылетает эксэпшон, как я понимаю, ругается на несколько запущенных одновременно транзакций. В связи с этим такой вопрос, можно ли как то управлять транзакциями (какой-нибудь механизм) или есть что-то врое join для транзакций?! В общем, подскажите, может кто уже сталкивался с этим.

**То есть вопрос следующий: как вызвать последовательно несколько обращений к БД без эксэпшона?** И еще, для соединения из java использую JDBC!

Сам код программы смысла выкладывать нет, так как нет конкретного места исключения, а вот код исключения, пожалуйста:

> `java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
> ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found`
>
> `at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
> at Persistance.connectDB.connectToBase(connectDB.java:140)
> at Persistance.connectDB.getVisitorByID(connectDB.java:35)
> at model.Search.getInfoByID(Search.java:31)
> at model.Search.getInfoAboutAll(Search.java:57)
> at view.Talons.refresh(Talons.java:506)
> at view.Talons.access$14(Talons.java:504)
> at view.Talons$7.actionPerformed(Talons.java:452)`
>
> `...`
>
> `Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
> ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found`
>
> `at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:395)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
> ... 49 more`

Comment: Код и екзепшн выложи!

Comment: Есть такая проблема с XE. IMHO это сознательное решение разработчиков, чтобы для продакшен (пусть даже tiny) Oracle покупали.

Посмотрите в сторону организации пула соединений. Когда-то делал,, но сейчас отошел от этой темы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте коннект к БД с использованием чисто Ораклёвых фич:

```
OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("username");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost.domain:port:XE");
dataSource.getConnection();
dataSource.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true); //ключевое место это
```

Answer (score 2):

Как сказал [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) - делаете connection pool на основе ConcurrentLinkedQueue или любой другой коллекции с использованием lock'ов или семафоров. Таким образом каждый метод будет использовать свой объект connection'a. Хотя для полноты я бы попросил выложить один из методов подключения к бд(без логики того, что происходит с бд, а с тем как вы открываете транзакции, как их закрываете и что вообще у Вас там происходит)
P.S. хотя как вариант можете использовать уже готовые реализации connection pool'ов